# Android - View.animate skipping

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I'm working on animating a View from within a GridLayout. When I access the view from the `View.OnClickListener onClick(View view)` method the animation runs smoothly.

However, when I get Views via `gridLayout.getChildAt(i)` the animation skips straight to the ending position.

```
                view.animate()
                    .translationX(viewAnimation.xTransform)
                    .translationY(viewAnimation.yTransform)
                    .setDuration(200)
                    .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
                            //Code
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                            if (reloadGrid)
                              //Code
                            else
                                animate(viewAnimations);
                        }

                        //Other methods here
                    });
```

I'm really unsure as to why when the View is passed as a parameter it animates fine, however otherwise it skips.

Any advice would be great!

**Edit**
I have also checked and the difference between the 2 'View' objects is one has `mDrawable` set and one doesn't. I believe this could be the cause?

Comment: It basically depends on what view you placed the click listener. I'm guessing it's on the grid layout. That's why you need to find each view

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why this solves the problem, however accessing each View within the GridLayout via `findViewById(i)` seems to work, and then allow the animation to run smoothly.

This took way too long to figure out.